# SQL Server 2012 clean up sql program repeatability

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that I run in SQL Server 2012 RDBMS where I am declaring a variable and looking up that variable in several reference tables. I have added the "IF EXISTS(...)" clause because I don't want to see an empty table returned if there is no match with my variable.  After the "IF EXISTS(...)", I run the 'look-up' query for my variable.

Adding the "IF EXISTS(...)" has slowed down this lookup significantly.  Is there a more programmatic way of achieving the same results? I only want tables returned when they match on the variable, and I would like to make my code more efficient and less repetitive... I am doing about 50-60 look-ups all at once.  How can I make this code more efficient, and more proficient?

Here is the form of the query now:

```
    DECLARE @PhN as varchar(30)
    SET @PhN = 'MyVariable'

    IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from ref.T1 x where x.TN_NBR = @PhN)
        select 'ref.T1' as [ref.T1], * from ref.T1 x where x.TN_NBR = @PhN
    IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from ref.T2 x where x.TN = @PhN or x.BILL_NUM = @PhN)
        select 'ref.T2' as [ref.T2], * from ref.T2 x where x.TN = @PhN or x.BILL_NUM = @PhN

    -- ... This pattern continues about fifty times ...

    IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from ref.Tn x where x.TFN = @PhN)
        select 'ref.Tn' as [ref.Tn], * from ref.Tn x where x.TFN = @PhN
    IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from ref.Tn2 x where x.ENI_800_NUMBER = @PhN or x.ENI_POTS_NUMBER = @PhN)
        select 'ref.Tn2' as [ref.Tn2], * from ref.Tn2 x where x.ENI_800_NUMBER = @PhN or x.ENI_POTS_NUMBER = @PhN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary table like this:

```
DECLARE @PhN as varchar(30)
SET @PhN = 'MyVariable'


select top * from ref.T1 x INTO #tmp1 where x.TN_NBR = @PhN 
IF EXISTS(select top 1 * from #tmp1)
  select 'ref.T1' as [ref.T1], * from #tmp1
```

etc

Comment: Interesting... I'm going to test to see if that is indeed faster.  3 'selects' compared to 2 to begin with.

Comment: @ColinMac - it really is only one -- it should be the case that #tmp1 will fit in memory and never be written to disk since it is just one (or a few) row(s).  It all comes down to indexes and relative size -- if ref.T1.TN_NBR was indexed you would not have originally complained about the two selects (since they would have been `O(1)`) so the issue was the scan time of ref.T1.  How many rows does it have?  Any number that you would notice a difference in time between one and two runs should show an improvement with this code.  oh... unless you fill up temp space or memory.

Comment: Hmm - well in a test the original is faster.  I suppose I don't really care about optimizing this query -- however I am interested in coding this in a way that doesn't look so repetitive...  It strikes me as primitive and not following guidelines of software (such as "don't repeat yourself")

Comment: @ColinMac - You mean the original `IF EXISTS()`?  -- What you are doing is primitve -- you using an ad-hoc tool to perform a script task.  If you want something non primitive then you are going to have to move to a different platform (eg custom C# program).  You could get rid of the "repetition" by putting the SQL statements in a table and running them in a loop with EXEC, but in my opinion anything that uses a loop in SQL is ugly.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for...  I'll have to give that a shot.  

If I write a procedure, I'd like it to return results as soon as it's done running, and I don't want to write the results to a table and look at the table or anything like that...  You have a grasp on this -- how might that be done?  This 'ad hoc' tool, while just that, is useful on a regular basis as a lookup while doing investigative work.  Ease and quickness-of-use matters to me in this case.

Comment: Using a temporary table is no different than using a variable ins SQL Server.  I don't have any interest in writing a tool for you -- and I won't show you how to use a loop since (as I said) I think it worse in every way from this solution.  No good ever came from loops in SQL.

Comment: For the time being, and for my colleagues, I think the tool suites the purpose.  Cheers